# 2 Questions about Philosophy and Best Practices in Database Development

Tags: database, database-design

Which one is best, regarding the implementation of a database for a web application: a lean and very small database with only the bare information, sided with a application that "recalculates" all the secondary information, on demand, based on those basic ones, OR, a database filled with all those secondary information already previously calculated, but possibly outdated?

Obviously, there is a trade-of there and I think that anyone would say that the best answer to this question is: "depends" or "is a mix between the two". But I'm really not to comfortable or experienced enough to reason alone about this subject. Could someone share some thoughts?

Also, another different question:
Should a database be the "snapshot" of a particular moment in time or should a database accumulate all the information from previous time, allowing the retrace of what happened? For instance, let's say that I'm modeling a Bank Account. Should I only keep the one's balance on that day, or should I keep all the one's transactions, and from those transactions infer the balance?

Any pointer on this kind of stuff that is, somehow, more deep in database design?

Thanks

Comment: Consider posting 2 questions when asking 2 questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My quick answer would be to store everything in the database. **The cost of storage is far lower than the cost of processing** when talking about very large scale applications. On small scale applications, the data would be far less, so storage would still be an appropriate solution.

Most RDMSes are extremely good at handling vast amounts of data, so when there are millions/trillions of records, the data can still be extracted relatively quickly, which can't be said about processing the data manually each time.

If you choose to calculate data rather than store it, the processing time doesn't increase at the same rate as the size of data does - the more data ~ the more users. This would generally mean that processing times would multiply by the data's size **and** the number of users.

```
processing_time = data_size * num_users
```

---

To answer your other question, I think it would be best practice to introduce a "snapshot" of a particular moment **only when data amounts to such a high value that processing time will be significant**.

When calculating large sums, such as bank balances, it would be good practice to store the result of any heavy calculations, along with their date stamp, to the database. This would simply mean that they will not need calculating again until it becomes out of date.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to ever have out of date pre-calulated values. That's what trigger are for (among other things). However for most applications, I would not start precalculating until you need to. It may be that the calculation speed is always there. Now in a banking application, where you need to pre-calculate from thousands or even millions of records almost immediately, yes, design a precalulation process bases on triggers that adjust the values every time they are changed.

As to whether to store just a picture in time or historical values, that depends largely on what you are storing. If it has anything to do with financial data, store the history. You will need it when you are audited. Incidentally, design to store some data as of the date of the action (this is not denormalization). For instance, you have an order, do not rely onthe customer address table or the product table to get data about where the prodcts were shipped to or what they cost at the time of the order. This data changes over time and then you orders are no longer accurate. You don't want your financial reports to change the dollar amount sold because the price changed 6  months later.

There are other things that may not need to be stored historically. In most applications we don't need to know that you were Judy Jones 2 years ago and are Judy Smith now (HR application are usually an exception).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say start off just tracking the data you need and perform the calculations on the fly, but throughout the design process and well into the test/production of the software keep in mind that you may have to switch to storing the pre-calculated values at some point.  Design with the ability to move to that model if the need arises.

Adding the pre-calculated values is one of those things that sounds good (because in many cases it *is* good) but might not be needed.  Keep the design as simple as it needs to be.  If performance becomes an issue in doing the calculations on the fly, then you can add fields to the database to store the calculations and run a batch overnight to catch up and fill in the legacy data.

As for the banking metaphor, definitely store a complete record of all transactions.  Store any data that's relevant.  A database should be a store of data, past and present.  Audit trails, etc.  The "current state" can either be calculated on the fly or it can be maintained in a flat table and re-calculated during writes to other tables (triggers are good for that sort of thing) if performance demands it.

Comment: When you have 2 opposite design choices and go for one, is it easy or realistic to expect that once you reach test or production phase you can switch to the other design?I have read such suggestions here and there but I am not sure if it is indeed possible in non-trivial projects.

Comment: @user384706: It should always be possible to change aspects of the design later on, especially in non-trivial projects.  You can predict how the application is going to behave in production, but in the end that's just speculation.  Changing business needs, unexpected environmental changes, scaling to accommodate growth, etc.  If the design of the code and/or the data is so iron clad that it's a ridiculous notion to change it, then it wasn't designed very well from the beginning.  The software is going to change, prepare for that change from the start.

Comment: @user384706: Also, these two choices aren't really "opposite."  The pre-calculated data can easily be added to the existing audit trail of data after the fact.  At least, that's been my experience in the past.  If this particular project has some subtleties to make that difficult then those weren't conveyed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends :) Persisting derived data in the database can be useful because it enables you to implement constraints and other logic against it. Also it can be indexed or you may be able to put the calculations in a view. In any case, try to stick to Boyce-Codd / 5th Normal Form as a guide for your database design. Contrary to what you may sometimes hear, normalization does *not* mean you cannot store derived data - it just means data shouldn't be derived from nonkey attributes in the same table.

Fundamentally any database is a record of the known facts at a particular point in time. Most databases include some time component and some data is preserved whereas some is not - requirements should dictate this.

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question.

Any choices that you make depend on the requirements of the application.

Sometimes speed wins, sometimes space wins.  Sometime data accuracy wins, sometimes snapshots win.

While you may not have the ability to tell what's important, the person you're solving the problem for should be able to answer that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I like dynamic programming(not calculate anything twise). If you're not limited with space and are fine with a bit outdated data, then precalculate it and store in the DB. This will give you additional benefit of being able to run sanity checks and ensure that data is always consistent.

But as others already replied, it depends :)

Comment: no need for it to be out of date... either triggers, materialized views or query caches can keep it up-to-date